# Another probability question - 6 choices, half are right...

Tags: probability

Twenty years after high school stats I can't remember that much so please forgive me asking what are basics...

I have a stimulus experiment where respondents are presented with 6 pieces of data.  Three pieces are correct, three are incorrect. The respondent is asked to choose which they believe to be correct.

**Q.** Am I right in assuming that they have a 50% chance of merely guessing the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the respondent is asked to simply choose a correct piece out of the six, the probability that he gets it right is $50\%$ ($=3$ chances out of $6$).

If he is asked to label each piece as correct/incorrect (but he is not told how many are correct), the probability he gets them all right is $1/64$, because there are $2^6$ ways to label six items as correct/incorrect, and only one labeling is everywhere right.

Finally, if he is told that exactly three pieces are correct and is asked to pick those out of the six on the table, the probability is $1/20$. There are ${{6}\choose{3}} = 20$ combinations of three objects out of six, and only one is the correct 3-tuple.